# Find and replace within nested array

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays that are structured differently, I want to check `allItems` and replace anything that exists in `newItems`. I have try using `map` but I'm not sure how to deal with nested arrays of objects.

```
const allItems = [
  {
    'id': 1,
    'text': 'old',
    'child': [
      {
        'id': 2,
        'text': 'old'
      }
    ]
  }
]

const newItems = [
  {
    'id': 1,
    'text': 'new',
    'more_info': 'abcd'
  },
  {
    'id': 2,
    'text': 'new',
    'more_info': 'abcd'
  }
]
```

I want to return:

```
  {
    'id': 1,
    'text': 'new',
    'more_info': 'abcd',
    'child': [
      {
        'id': 2,
        'text': 'new'
        'more_info': 'abcd'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My code (this doesn't deal with the child level):

```
const result = allItems.map(x => {
  const item = newItems.find(({ id }) => id === x.id)
  return item ? item : x
})
```

Comment: This seems to be related to a previous question.

Answer (score 1):

`child` property represents only one, but this alternative loops the whole array.

You can use recursion to go deeper and updated the found objects by `id`.

*This approach mutates the original array*

```js
const allItems = [{  'id': 1,  'text': 'old',  'child': [    {      'id': 2,      'text': 'old'    }  ]}],
      newItems = [  {    'id': 1,    'text': 'new',    'more_info': 'abcd'  },  {    'id': 2,    'text': 'new',    'more_info': 'abcd'  }]
      looper = (arr, items) => {
        arr.forEach(outer => {
          let found = items.find(n => outer.id === n.id);
          if (found) {
            Object.assign(outer, found);
            if (outer.child) looper(outer.child, items);
          }
        });
      };

looper(allItems, newItems);
console.log(allItems);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will give you some hints on how to approach this problem, without providing the final answer.

### Two Approaches

There are two approaches you can take to solve this problem:

1. Implement a `findItemById(id)` method that recursively traverses through `allItems` to find an item with a specific `id`. Then you can call that function for each entry in `newItems` and override the relevant properties if you find it.
2. Implement a `traverseItems(itemTree, callback)` method that recursively traverses each level of the item tree, and then calls `callback` with each item and child item it comes across. The callback would then check if that item's ID matches one in `newItems` and if so, overwrites it's properties with those from the entry in `newItems`.

### Commonalities

If you think about these two approaches, it becomes obvious that the thing needed in both approaches is a recursive traversal function that can go down through all the levels of `allItems`. So focus on getting that basic algorithm right, and then you can decide between the two. (Hint: one of them is likely to be more efficient than the other, but for small data sets, it really won't matter).